# Installing mysql2 gem on mac with RVM is real pain

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, installation, mysql2

Step 1:--

```
    rails s/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib (LoadError)
    Referenced from: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    Reason: image not found - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/mohit/projects/lbs_admin/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

STEP 2:--

```
 sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Result:--

```
    rails sWARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.2) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
    WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    => Call with -d to detach
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    Exiting
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_connection': Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter) (RuntimeError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:68:in `establish_connection'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1891:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/will_paginate-3.0.pre2/lib/will_paginate/finders/active_record.rb:31:in `enable!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/will_paginate-3.0.pre2/lib/will_paginate/railtie.rb:9:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
        from /Users/mohit/projects/lbs_admin/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/mohit/projects/lbs_admin/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from /Users/mohit/projects/lbs_admin/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from /Users/mohit/projects/lbs_admin/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /Users/mohit/projects/lbs_admin/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:248:in `wrapped_app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:213:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Step 3:--

```
sudo gem uninstall mysql2
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql_config
```

Current status:--

ruby -v

```
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
```

rails -v

Rails 3.0.3

gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.7, 3.0.3)
actionpack (3.0.7, 3.0.3)
activemodel (3.0.7, 3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.7, 3.0.3)
activeresource (3.0.7, 3.0.3)
activesupport (3.0.7, 3.0.3)
annotate-models (1.0.4)
arel (2.0.9)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.12)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
mysql2 (0.3.2)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.2)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.7, 3.0.3)
railties (3.0.7, 3.0.3)
rake (0.8.7)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.27)
web-app-theme (0.6.3)
will_paginate (3.0.pre2)
```

locate mysql_config

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql_config
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64/man/man1/mysql_config.1
```

bundle show mysql2

```
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.3.2
```

locate libmysqlclient.16.dylib

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: It's a real pain in most OSs as it requires native bindings. I dream of the day we'll have a pure ruby implementation of the driver :(. I should add that I couldn't build the gem with Mysql 5.5, but it did work with mysql 5.1. I'll try to remember what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rails sWARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.2) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
    WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x

MySql version '0.2.7' solved my issue.

```
 gem 'mysql2', '0.2.7'
```

Answer (score 6):

I have the sam problem.  What I did is doing;

```
gem install --version '0.2.7' mysql2
```

Then on your Rails's GemFile.  Should look like this.

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.2.7'
```

Then try again.  Hope it help.

Comment: This should also work, only just noticed this now.  Although my (updated) solution using `"~> 0.2"` is slightly better because it frees bundler up to use other 0.2 bugfix releases if they're available.

Comment: I think you mean "~> 0.2.7". OTOH, "~> 0.2" would allow anything less than 1.0. See [pessimistic version constraint](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#declaring-dependencies).

Comment: man -- i wasted 3 hours before finding this post.  They have got to get this gem cleaned up

Answer (score 2):

Your stacktrace after *Step 2* told you what to do:

> Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter`

#### Update

Also, upgrade your Rails to 3.0.7 - there are a number of security holes (and bugs) in 3.0.3.

#### Update

Looks like that error message from Rails is wrong, it should have read:

> Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.1

Ie. for anything less than 3.1 you need to pin mysql2 to the 0.2 release, and not allow it to use 0.3.  To do this, change your mysql2 line in your Gemfile to this:

```
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2"
```

Then re-run `bundle install`

Comment: Already did.. :) I wasted my whole day dude.. and thats y finally moved back to 1.8.7 with rails 3.0.7

Comment: Btw, the move back to 1.8.7 probably just means that you moved back to a mysql2 version of 0.2.x.  Ie. I don't think this is a 1.9.2 v. 1.8.7 issue (because I can reproduce here with 1.8.7)

Comment: Working perfectly at @ruby1.8.7 and mysql 0.3.2 and rails 3.0.7. But definetley ur point is valid. But i can't mess with it as i am middle of very crucial project. But will definitely try once its over.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (but I cannot guarantee anything)

- Check [this](http://geryit.com/blog/2011/01/installing-mysql-with-rails-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/) post about how to

  - remove MySQL 5.5.
  - install [MySQL 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#downloads) (I think I downloaded the 32bit DMG version)
- Follow [this](http://sampierson.com/blog/system-administration/installing-ruby-mysql-gem-on-mac-os-x-leopard/) post to create the GEM.

Hopefully it will work after this. I'll cross my fingers for you.

Comment: I'm using RVM too, those instructions *should* work. I say should, because I installed it on my personal computer, and I'm not at work, so I can't check a few things (like exactly which version of mysql I downloaded, although I remember it was 5.1.X). Just curiosity, which part do you think doesn't work with RVM?

Comment: @Augusto Oh no... He is using mysql. I am already using mysql2 for tons of my projects. All the servers are running msql2

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll check tonight which if I compiled mysql2 following the same instructions, as the parameters to build both gems are quite similar.

Answer (score 1):

The above problem occurs presently on EngineYard App Cloud with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.3. Using mysql 2.8.1 barfs b/c EY sets mysql2 adapter. Using mysql2 0.3.2 barfs. So I was seriously stumped. Props to Richard Soutar's answer. It worked.